# returning two rows using a GROUP BY clause in sql server 08

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a following table:

```
acc_name        dr_amt     cr_amt

Cash in hand    10000     0
Share Capital   00      1000
Cash in hand    2000      0
Share Capital   0        2000.00
Vehicles        5000      0
Cash in hand    0         5000
```

With the following query,

```
SELECT    a.acc_name, sum(j.dr_amt) AS dr_sum, sum(j.cr_amt) AS cr_sum
FROM      journal_voucher_details_mcg AS j 
INNER JOIN  acc_head_mcg AS a ON a.acc_code = j.acc_code 
INNER JOIN  journal_voucher_mcg AS jv ON jv.jv_no = j.jv_no
WHERE       jv.jv_date = '2011-04-08'
GROUP BY    a.acc_name
```

I'm able to get the following results:

```
acc_name        dr_sum  cr_sum  

Cash in hand    3000    5000
Share Capital   0      3000
Vehicles        5000    0
```

But I want two entries for Cash in hand (and for any entry which has both dr_sum and cr_sum greater than 0) and the result should be as follows:

```
acc_name        dr_sum  cr_sum  

Cash in hand    3000    0
Cash in hand    0       5000
Share Capital   0      3000
Vehicles        5000    0
```

I also need the sum of both dr_sum and cr_sum which in this case should be 8000 to both....My final query is

```
SELECT *, SUM(dr_sum), SUM(cr_sum)
FROM (SELECT a.acc_name, sum(j.dr_amt) AS dr_sum, sum(j.cr_amt) AS cr_sum 
FROM        journal_voucher_details_mcg AS j 
INNER JOIN  acc_head_mcg AS a ON a.acc_code = j.acc_code 
INNER JOIN  journal_voucher_mcg AS jv ON jv.jv_no = j.jv_no
WHERE       jv.jv_date = '2011-04-08'
GROUP BY    j.acc_code)
```

But this one's not working....will really appreciate your efforts guys!!!

**Edit**

Final resultset:

```
acc_name        dr_sum  cr_sum  

Cash in hand    3000    0
Cash in hand    0       5000
Share Capital   0      3000
Vehicles        5000    0
Total           8000    8000
```

I'm not able to display the "Total" (the word Total) in the last tuple's first field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the current SQL you have is fine you should not change this.
If you need to split and have both entries separated you can do this:

```
WITH W_RESULT AS (
   -- your current query goes here....
)
SELECT acc_name, dr_sum, 0 AS cr_sum
FROM W_RESULT
WHERE dr_sum <> 0
UNION
SELECT acc_name, 0 AS dr_sum, cr_sum
FROM W_RESULT
WHERE cr_sum <> 0
```

**following the updated solution including discussion form comments**

```
WITH W_RESULT AS (
   -- your current query goes here....
)
SELECT acc_name, dr_sum, 0 AS cr_sum
FROM W_RESULT
WHERE dr_sum <> 0
UNION
SELECT acc_name, 0 AS dr_sum, cr_sum
FROM W_RESULT
WHERE cr_sum <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total' AS acc_name, SUM(dr_sum), SUM(cr_sum)
FROM W_RESULT
```

previous discussion...

for the total sum you can add to your query `sum(j.dr_amt + j.cr_amt) AS t_sum` and if you need this also as as separate entry in the result set you can expand the above solution using WITH-clause and UNION with the additional column and one extra UNION section. Or maybe even simpler like this:

```
WITH W_RESULT AS (
   -- your current query goes here....
)
SELECT acc_name, dr_sum, 0 AS cr_sum, 0 AS t_sum
FROM W_RESULT
WHERE dr_sum <> 0
UNION
SELECT acc_name, 0 AS dr_sum, cr_sum, 0 AS t_sum
FROM W_RESULT
WHERE cr_sum <> 0
UNION
SELECT acc_name, 0 AS dr_sum, 0 AS cr_sum, dr_sum + cr_sum AS t_sum
FROM W_RESULT
```

**important**

the current query from the question I'm referring to is the first one.
The "final query" at the end of the question is a bit strange.

It does something like

- sum of "Cash in hand 3000" +  "Vehicles 5000" = 8000 as dr_sum
- sum of "Cash in hand 5000" +  "Share Capital 3000" = 8000 as cr_sum

I was assuming that a total_sum was requested that does something like

- sum of "Cash in hand 3000" +  "Cash in hand 5000" = 8000 as t_sum
- sum of "Share Capital 3000" = 3000 as t_sum
- sum of "Vehicles 5000" = 5000 as t_sum

Please add a comment witch sum is the correct one.

Comment: I need the sum of all the amounts in dr_sum column and cr_column respectively...so your first assumption is correct. I want the sum to be displayed as a final tuple  something like `... UNION SELECT  SUM(dr_sum), SUM(cr_sum) FROM W_RESULT` . But I can't get the word "Total" to be displayed as a field in the last tuple. Please see my edits above for further clarifications.

Comment: adding this union should do the trick.  `UNION SELECT 'Total' AS acc_name, SUM(dr_sum), SUM(cr_sum) FROM W_RESULT`

Comment: updated the answer with the complete solution. (Adding the last `Total` with an `UNION ALL` will place it as last row)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** after seeing the clarified requirement.

```
WITH groups AS (
  SELECT
    a.acc_name,
    dr_sum = sum(j.dr_amt),
    cr_sum = sum(j.cr_amt)
  FROM journal_voucher_details_mcg AS j
    INNER JOIN acc_head_mcg AS a ON a.acc_code = j.acc_code 
    INNER JOIN journal_voucher_mcg AS jv ON jv.jv_no = j.jv_no
  WHERE jv.jv_date = '2011-04-08'
  GROUP BY j.acc_code, CASE WHEN dr_amt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
)

SELECT
  acc_name,
  dr_sum,
  cr_sum
FROM groups

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'Total',
  SUM(dr_sum),
  SUM(cr_sum)
FROM groups
```

Comment: I need only a tuple for the total debit and credit sum...currently this query gives me two columns with the total values repeated.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as
(
  select
    a.acc_name,
    case n.n when 1 then sum(j.dr_amt) else 0 end as dr_sum,
    case n.n when 2 then sum(j.cr_amt) else 0 end as cr_sum
  from journal_voucher_details_mcg as j 
    inner join  acc_head_mcg as a
      on a.acc_code = j.acc_code 
    inner join journal_voucher_mcg as jv
      on jv.jv_no = j.jv_no
    cross join (select 1 union all select 2) as n(n)
  where jv.jv_date = '2011-04-08'
  group by a.acc_name, n.n   
)
select
  acc_name,
  dr_sum,
  cr_sum
from cte
where not (dr_sum = 0 and cr_sum = 0)
union all
select 
  'Total',
  sum(dr_sum),
  sum(cr_sum)
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 (new feature in 2008), you can add a `WITH ROLLUP` to your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
        a.acc_name, sum(j.dr_amt) AS dr_sum, sum(j.cr_amt) AS cr_sum 
FROM        
        journal_voucher_details_mcg AS j 
INNER JOIN  
        acc_head_mcg AS a ON a.acc_code = j.acc_code 
INNER JOIN  
        journal_voucher_mcg AS jv ON jv.jv_no = j.jv_no
WHERE       
        jv.jv_date = '2011-04-08'
GROUP BY    
        j.acc_code WITH ROLLUP
```

In that case, you'll get additional rows, in which the `acc_code` is NULL - that's your line with the totals over all accounts.

So your new output should look something like this:

```
acc_name        dr_sum  cr_sum  

Cash in hand    3000      0
Cash in hand    0         5000
Share Capital   0         3000
Vehicles        5000      0
NULL            8000      8000   <-- that's the line with the totals
```